# Asking for inputs in my script

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to prompt the user to input number of users to run and email addresses to populate a csv file. I am getting some syntax error. How do I get this working ?

```
enter code here

import csv

# Define users 
valid_input = False
while not valid_input:
    users =raw_input('Number of users: ')
    try:
        users = range(0,int(users)
        valid_input = True
    except:
        print "Invalid input"
        pass

First_Name = ["Test"+str(user) for user in range(1, users+1)]
Last_Name = ["User%s" %user for user in users]
email_addresses = []
for user in users:
    email= raw_input("Email domain for user %d: " %user)
    email_addresses.append(last_names[user] + email)
Password = ["Password1" for user in users]
Group =["Test" for user in users]
Admin = ["Yes" for user in users]
# open a file for writing.
# open a file for writing.
with open('users.csv', 'wb') as csv_out:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_out)
    writer.writerows(zip(Email_Address, Password, First_Name, Last_Name, Group, Admin))
```

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
Email_Address = (raw_input('Email_Address') [Last_Names + "Email_Address " for Last_Names   inLast_Name]])
```

is invalid syntax. It's actually very difficult to tell what you're trying to do with that line, but it is very invalid syntax.

Also you seem to be misunderstanding iteration in python. On your first line you prompt for a single number and then try to iterate through it in multiple other places, which I'm guessing is pretty far from your intention.

```
users = (raw_input('number of users'))
```

will set users equal to a single string. I'm guessing that what you'd actually want is something more like this:

```
valid_input = False
while not valid_input:
    users =raw_input('Number of users: ')
    try:
        users = range(0,int(users))
        valid_input = True
    except:
        print "Invalid input"
        pass
```

I've been reading through the code some more and while it seems to be pretty far from what you've written there, I'm guessing that you want to prompt the user for an email address for each user. If that is indeed the case, this is how you would do it:

```
email_addresses = []
for user in users:
    email = raw_input("Email address for user %d: " %user)
    email_addresses.extend([email + last_name for last_name in last_names])
```

Apparently I was mistaken about your intent, here's a solution for what you're looking for:

```
email_addresses = []
for user in users:
    email= raw_input("Email domain for user %d: " %user)
    email_addresses.append(last_names[user] + email)
```

Also, a couple style notes:

- Try to keep all of your variable names as descriptive as possible. For instance, the last_name list you've got doesn't actually have last names, but holds user ids, so user_ids would be a better name
- If you are going to adopt a pluralization nomenclature then make sure to pluralize lists and then make sure that the items can be referenced as the singular version instead of the other way around. For example:

  last_name = [#some list]
  [#something for last_names in last_name]

is just confusing. It should be:

```
last_names = [#some_list]
[#something for last_name in last_names]
```

- Choose either snake case (like_this) or title case (likeThis) and stick with it. Nothing is more annoying than having to scroll through a lost codebase and figure out which case a particular variable is using.

Comment: Well, apparently the square bracket I spotted isn't the only problem ;-)

Comment: I am trying to ask the user to input an  email domain say @gmail.com. Then it will take the Last_Name and join the two and have User1@gmail.com. This depends on the number of users you have put in for users.

Comment: @user2547206 ooh, alright, editing response

Comment: I am getting a sytax error on the users                               valid_input = False
while !valid_input:
    users = raw_input('Number of users: ')
    try:
        users = range(0,int(users)
        valid_input = True
    except:
        print "Invalid input"
        pass

Comment: @Wachira ah, forgot python doesn't have bang nots, updated.

Comment: I have updated the code but I am still getting syntax error ?

Comment: @Wachira There was a missing paren, but that really should be the kind of error you can troubleshoot by yourself

Answer (score 0):

I'm not into Python at all, but it seems to be 1 square bracket too much at the end of this line :

```
Email_Address = (raw_input('Email_Address') [Last_Names + "Email_Address " for Last_Names   inLast_Name]])
```

Comment: yes there's an extra square bracket, but that's far from the only problem with that line.

Answer (score 0):

After this line:

```
users = (raw_input('number of users'))
```

`users` is a string.  Let's say you enter 100.

Now, you iterate over `users`:

```
First_Name = ["Test"+str(user) for user in users]
```

Strings are iterable, so `user` takes on the individual characters of the string `'100'`. That is, `user` will first be `'1'`, then `'0'`, then `'0'` again; you get `Test1` then `Test0` then `Test0` rather than the 100 items I expect you expect.

You probably want to convert the input to an integer:

```
users = int(raw_input('number of users'))
```

And then iterate over a range (I'm assuming you want `1` through `n` rather than `0` through `n-1`:

```
First_Names = ["Test"+str(user) for user in range(1, users+1)]
```

I've also taken the liberty of changing the name of your variable to `First_Names` as what you have is a *list* of the first names, not a single first name.

Unfortunately, I don't really have the time to go into the rest of the problems with your code, of which there are many (including the question about input that you're actually asking), but that ought to get you started fixing it up.

Comment: First_Names = ["Test"+str(user) for user in range(1, users+1)]        I am getting TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list

Comment: No, you're not. There is no way that line can give you that error. The error is on another line. As I said, there are problems on other lines as well.